# Create a CommentList component from a json file submissions reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, netlify

I am trying to implement my own commenting system.
I already set up the comment form and I receive data in my netlify form submissions.
Then, I use the plugin `netlify-plugin-form-submissions`, which transforms your netlify form submissions into a json file (in my case in `Form submissions data saved: static/comments/approved-comments_submissions.json`)

So I am trying to retrieve the submissions data and make them appear as a comment list below my form.

Here is my CommentList Component:

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

import "./styles.module.css";

class CommentsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          commentList: "../../static/comments/approved-comments_submissions.json"
        } 
    }

  renderComments() {
      return this.state.commentList.map((item, index) => (
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <p>{item.data.name} a commenté le {item.created_on}</p>
                    <p>{item.data.commentaire}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        ));
      }
  

  render() {
      return (
          <div className="CommentsList">
              {this.renderComments()}
          </div>
      );
  }
}
export default CommentsList;
```

however it does not work, **I can't retrieve the data from approved-comments_submissions**. I have the following error:

`TypeError: this.state.commentList.map is not a function`

**Besides, how can I render the comments only in the right urlpage?** Because comments need to appear only in the right page

Here is an exemple of the data submission json file

```
[{"number":19,"title":null,"email":"email@email","name":"firstname", "summary":"testing","body":"testing","data":{"urlpage":"https://blabla.com/the/right/page/","name":"firstname","email":"email@email","commentaire":"testing"},"ip":"1.1.1.1","created_at":"2022-03-21T14:55:57.736Z","id":"aaaaaaaaa","form_id":"bbbbbbbb","site_url":"https://blabla.com","form_name":"approved-comments"}]
```

Here is my CommentForm code.

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { NetlifyForm, Honeypot } from 'react-netlify-forms'
import { useState } from "react"
import { useNetlifyForm, NetlifyFormProvider, NetlifyFormComponent} from "react-netlify-forms"
import { useFormik } from 'formik'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

import "./styles.module.css";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    input: { 
        minHeight: 100,
    },
  }));

const Commentbox = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const netlify = useNetlifyForm({
      name: 'approved-comments',
      action: '/',
      honeypotName: 'bot-field',
      onSuccess: (response, context) => {
        console.log('Successfully sent form data to Netlify Server')
      }
    })
    const [touched, setTouched] = useState(false);
    const location = useLocation();

    const handleTouch = () => {
     setTouched(true);
    };
    const {
      handleSubmit,
      handleChange,
      handleBlur,
      errors,
      values
    } = useFormik({
      initialValues: { name: '', email: '', commentaire: '', urlpage: '' },
      onSubmit: (values, {setStatus, resetForm}) => {
          values.urlpage = "https://blabla.com" + location.pathname
          netlify.handleSubmit(null, values);
          resetForm();
          setStatus({success: true});
  },
      validate: (values) => {
        const errors = {}
        if (
          !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)
        ) {
          errors.email = 'Adresse email invalide'
        }
        return errors
      }
    })

    return (
    <NetlifyFormProvider {...netlify}>
        <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="approved-comments" />
        <h3>Leave a comment </h3>
        <NetlifyFormComponent onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Honeypot />
          {netlify.success && (
            <p sx={{ variant: 'alerts.success', p: 3 }}>
              Thx for your comment 
            </p>
          )}
          {netlify.error && (
            <p sx={{ variant: 'alerts.muted', p: 3 }}>
              Sorry .
            </p>
          )}
         <input 
          type="hidden" 
          name="urlpage" 
          id="urlpage"
        />
         <TextField
          required
          id="name"
          name='name'
          label="Nom"
          variant="outlined"
          fullWidth
          margin="normal"
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          error={errors.name}
          value={values.name}
          style = {{width: "70%"}}
        />
        <TextField
          required
          id="email"
          name='email'
          label="Email"
          variant="outlined"
          fullWidth
          margin="normal"
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          onFocus={handleTouch}
          error={errors.email}
          helperText={touched && !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email) ? 'Adresse email non valide' : ' '}
          value={values.email}
          style = {{width: "70%"}}         
        /> 
         <TextField
          id="commentaire"
          name='commentaire'
          label="Commentaire"
          variant="outlined"
          fullWidth
          margin="normal"
          multiline
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          error={errors.commentaire}
          value={values.commentaire}
          inputProps={{
            className: classes.input
          }}
          style = {{width: "70%"}}          
        />  
        {/* <input type='hidden' name='name' value='values.name' />
        <input type='hidden' name='email' value='values.email' />
        <input type='hidden' name='commentaire' value='values.commentaire' /> */}


        <button class="button button--lg button--primary" type="submit">
                Publiez votre commentaire
        </button> 
        
        </NetlifyFormComponent>
      </NetlifyFormProvider>
    )
    
  }

export default Commentbox;
```

**EDIT**

So now my code compiles

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import "./styles.module.css";
import commentList from '../../../static/comments/approved-comments_submissions.json'

const Comments = commentList.map((item) => {

    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>{item.data.name} a commenté le {item.created_on}</p>
            <p>{item.data.commentaire}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>

} )

class CommentsList extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
          <div>
              {Comments}
          </div>
      );
  }
}
export default CommentsList;
```

however comments are still not rendering below my comment form :/

Comment: commentList is a string. You will have to import the json file, then use the imported value.

Comment: @windowsill look at my edit, I modified my code, it is now compiling but still, comments are note appearing yet :/

Comment: Okay so in the const Comments, I forgot the "return" ^^